# Rails find or create based on two fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a venue model and i want to do this

```
Venue.find_or_create_by_
```

but i only want a new venue to be created if one with the same name and date do not already exist

For example

```
=> Venue(id: integer, location: string, showdate: datetime, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime)
```

A venue is unique and needs to be created if the location and the showdate are not present in the db

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You can chain columns together by using `_and_`. This should do the trick:

```
Venue.find_or_create_by_location_and_showdate(location, showdate)
```

Comment: Jeez, Rails and particularly Ruby continually amazes me. How does it know what that function means? Is there some kind of catch all find_or_create_by_* function that interprets it?

Comment: Actually nevermind, I just had a look at the Rails source - Rails uses a method_missing function which does a regex on the method called and decomposes it. It's genius. If anybody else is interested, check out active_record/base.rb in the Rails source.

Comment: Also acceptable is to pass them as arguments. Venue.find_or_create_by(:location => location, :showdate => showdate)

Answer (score 10):

In rails 4 you would do:

```
Venue.find_or_create_by(location: location, showdate: showdate)
```

Much prettier, if you ask me!

Answer (score 1):

```
my_class = ClassName.find_or_initialize_by_showdate_and_location(showdate,location)
my_class.update_attributes!
```

find_or_initialize method find by name and location in database. If record doesn't exist than it initialize new record with showdate and location.
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html This link will help you to figure out find_or_initialize and find_or_create.

Comment: Calling `.update_attributes!` without passing any attributes is pretty useless. `.save!` would be a much better option. And in this case, the requester has already said he wants to use `.find_or_create`, so you shouldn't have to initialize and save the record in two separate steps.

Comment: @vonconrad I have already provided link which give an idea about both the methods. Whatever user would like to use it. I was giving idea both methods are available.

Comment: using find_or_initialize overcomes the problem of trying to create a record when there are validations that are not met by a create. e.g. Migrating data from another system.