# Rails create two objects from one form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have two models with a has_one relationship between them. The `Event` class which "has_one" `Location`. What I am trying to achieve is in the form where I create an event, I have a "Where?" field which is populated asynchronously through the Foursquare API.

Since I could not possibly migrate the whole of the Foursquare API to my own database, I want to generate a Location entry in my database the first time a location is mentioned in an event.

At the moment the result I am looking for is completed, but I think I am using to many hidden fields and a lot of javascript assignments. Is there a better practice than the one I am using to achieve the same result?

**new.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for :event, :url=> new_event_path, :method => :get, :remote => :true, :html => {:class => 'form-horizontal'} do |f| %>

   <%= fields_for :location do |f1|%>
   <%= f1.hidden_field :lat, :id=> 'foursquare-latitude' %>
   <%= f1.hidden_field :lng, :id => 'foursquare-longitude' %>
   <%= f1.hidden_field :foursquare_id, :id =>'foursquare-id' %>
   <%= f1.hidden_field :name, :id =>'location-name-field' %>

    <% end %>

    <!-- TODO Encapsulate in location model -->
    <%= f.hidden_field :latitude, :id=>'latitude-field' %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :longitude, :id=>'longitude-field' %>

<div class="control-group">
  <%= f.label :title , :class => "control-label" %>
  <div class="controls">
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="control-group">
  <label class="control-label" for="location">Where?</label>
  <div class="controls">
    <input type="text" id="location" data-provide="typeahead">
    <br/>
    <img src="../img/fsq.png" alt="Powered By Foursquare" width="240px" />
  </div>
</div>
<div class="control-group">
  <%= f.label :body, :class => "control-label" %>
  <div class="controls">
    <%= f.text_area :body, :rows => 6 %>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="control-group">
  <div class="controls">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
</div>

<% end %>
```

**events controller**

```
  def new
    @location = Location.new(params[:location])
    if @location.save
      @event = Event.new(params[:event])
      @event.author = current_user
      @event.location_id = @location.id
      respond_to do |format|
        if @event.save
          format.js  {render :action => "new"}
        else
          format.js  {render :action => "new"}
        end
      end
    end
  end
```

Comment: Might not be exactly what you're looking for but I was a little unclear about your question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3949864/rails-find-or-create-based-on-two-fields

Comment: Normally, it is perfectly possible to create one or more objects from a form. But (to me) your question is very unclear and I do not understand what the problem is. Try to explain it a little more, show your form code and model code for example so we can see what is missing in between (if you have some controller code already, it might be useful to show as well)

Comment: I have added some of my code, I can provide you with anything else you might think needs clarification

Comment: Try https://github.com/ryanb/nested_form